# Turn indicators don't work but hazards work fine

Tags: renault, indicators, clio

I have a 2011 Renault Clio.

This first started yesterday when my left indicator stopped working. None of the lights flash as they should and nothing happened on the dashboard, everything was completely dead with indicating left - my right indicators and hazard lights (left and right) worked fine.

Today my right indicators have also stopped working but the hazards still work OK.

I have also just noticed that when I indicate right my headlights come on, when I indicate left nothing happens but when I turn the left indicator off the headlights go off.

Answer (score 4):

> The hazards still work OK

This rules out that the indicator bulbs are not working.

> When I indicate right my headlights come on ... when I turn the left indicator off the headlights go off

Based on the image below, the headlight control is on the indicator stalk.

One possible explanation is that the the switches are not functioning as they should, possibly due to moisture/dirt ingression.

The likely fix will be to refurbish or replace the indicator stalk.

[image: Renault Clio dashboard]